# setting up java workspace in remote location

Tags: java

Forgive me for if its a dumb question.
I am new to java.
I want to set up my java workspace in a remote machine(server) and access the workspace from my desktop.

1) Is it required to have java installed on that remote machine?

2)While running the project whose computational resource(RAM) would be used i.e. my desktops or the remote servers'.

Comment: Define "Java workspace". Do you mean an Eclipse workspace?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I want that my project workspace sits on some remote server and i would be working from my laptop. So i wanted to know where to install JDK and the RAM size that i would choose for the remote server and my laptop. hope this helps.

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, you are right java workspace means my eclipse project workspace.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclise as IDE for development or Any IDE you need to install JDK on computer that you work(server or client)so if you are working  on remote server you need to install JDK on it 
and 
you should have a remote connection if you are in windows  ,use Remote Desktop ,

second question

if you are using a server as working computer that computer takes RAM to compile and run Java 
not your computer .

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Is it required to have java installed on that remote machine?
```

**Yes , of course you need it to be installed on the target computer you are accessing through remote**

```
2) While running the project whose computational resource(RAM) would be use
```

**While accessing jvm will use the RAM of the computer where it is being used , your pc doesnt get used only your network data usage would be used**

Hope this helps!!